# Implementing OCR on IOS

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, ocr

Was wondering if anyone had some idea on how one would implement OCR image linking on an IOS device.

What I exactly want the app to do is scan an image using the iPhones camera, then recognise that image. When the image is recognised the app should open a link that is relative to the image.

A better example of what I am talking about is made by a company called [Augment](http://augmentedev.com/trackers.php) . They make a product called "Trackers" which is exactly what I would like to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There are no in-build/custom SDK's that do your exact requirement.

However, you can achieve it by customizing the OpenCV library or any of Augmented reality SDK's.

Here are the links may helpful to you

[OpenCV library tutorial iOS](https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial)

[Wikitude Augmented reality](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/ios)

Answer (score -1):

Now there is [Real-Time Recognition SDK](http://rtrsdk.com) (http://rtrsdk.com).
It is free by the way. Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY